# sqLite not storing records for next month

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app. The activity will be opened asking for "Title", "Description ", "Venue Using Google API Place Picker", "Date And Time Using Date and Time Picker" and then clicks on Create Button causes data to be saved on DataBase.

The problem is when date of current month is selected by user from date picker is working fine and storing in DB but when user selects date of next months, it is not storing Data in Db for that entry.

Create.java

```
package com.example.akshay.eventmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;


/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/12/2015.
 */
public class Create extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button create;
    EditText title, desc, time, Venue;
    TextView venueInfo;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder;
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    public LatLng gotLatLng;
    String placeName;
    String plName;
    String Addr;
    Double gotLat, gotLong;
    String LAT, LONG;
    DataBaseHelper myDB;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Create";

    String GotTime = " ";
    String GotDate = " ";

    DatePickerDialog datePicker;
    TimePickerDialog myTimePicker;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    String TimeForDB;
    String DateForDB;
    int DayOfMonth;
    int MonthName;

    static boolean flag = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd", Locale.US);


        showDate();
        showTime();
        casting();
    }

    public void casting() {
        create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreate);
        Venue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etVenue);
        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
        time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTime);

        time.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);


        Venue.setOnClickListener(this);
        time.setOnClickListener(this);
        create.setOnClickListener(this);
        Venue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())

        {
            case R.id.etVenue:
                try {
                    intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

                    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(Create.this);


                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Create.this, "Google Play Services is not available.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }
                break;


            case R.id.bCreate:
                String TITLE = title.getText().toString();
                String DESC = desc.getText().toString();
                String eventTime = time.getText().toString();
                String PLACE = Venue.getText().toString();
                myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);


                int flag = myDB.InsertValues(TITLE, DESC, PLACE, LAT, LONG, Addr, DateForDB, TimeForDB, DayOfMonth, MonthName);



                if (flag == 1) {

                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , TITLE);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , DESC);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , PLACE);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , LAT);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , LONG);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , Addr);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , DateForDB);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , TimeForDB);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , String.valueOf(DayOfMonth));
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , String.valueOf(MonthName));
                    Toast.makeText(Create.this, String.valueOf(DayOfMonth), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(Create.this, String.valueOf(MonthName), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(Create.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Create.this, "Error Adding Records", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.etTime:
                myTimePicker.show();
                datePicker.show();
                break;

        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                gotLatLng = place.getLatLng();
                plName = (String) place.getName();
                Addr = (String) place.getAddress();
                gotLat = gotLatLng.latitude;
                gotLong = gotLatLng.longitude;
                LAT = String.valueOf(gotLat);
                LONG = String.valueOf(gotLong);
                placeName = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
                Toast.makeText(this, placeName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Venue.setText(plName);

            }
        }
    }

    public void showDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                DayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
                MonthName = monthOfYear;
                MonthName = MonthName+1;
                monthOfYear = monthOfYear+1;

                DateForDB = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
                GotDate = dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()).toString();


            }
        }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        flag = true;
    }

    public void showTime() {
        if (flag == true) {

            final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            myTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


                    Calendar newTime = Calendar.getInstance();

                    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    TimeForDB = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + " : " + String.valueOf(minute);
                    GotTime = GotDate + " At " + String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
                    time.setText(GotTime);

                }
            }, calender.get((Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
        }

    }
}
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.akshay.eventmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/12/2015.
 */
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DB_NAME = "MyEvents.db";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "MyEvents";

    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Title";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Description";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Venue";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Latitude";
    public static final String COL_6 = "Longitude";
    public static final String COL_7 = "Address";
    public static final String COL_8 = "Date";
    public static final String COL_9 = "Time";
    public static final String COL_10 = "Day_Of_Month";
    public static final String COL_11 = "Month";
    SQLiteDatabase myDB;

    int date, month;
    Calendar c;
    final static String Log_Tag = "CheckDataBase";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_2 + " TEXT," + COL_3 + " TEXT,"
                + COL_4 + " TEXT," + COL_5 + " TEXT," + COL_6 + " TEXT," + COL_7 + " TEXT," + COL_8 + " TEXT," + COL_9 + " TEXT," + COL_10 + " INTEGER ," + COL_11 + " INTEGER)");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exist " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public Integer InsertValues(String title, String Desc, String Venue, String Lat, String Long, String Addr, String Date, String Time, int DayOfMonth, int MonthName)

    {

        myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cV = new ContentValues();
        cV.put(COL_2, title);
        cV.put(COL_3, Desc);
        cV.put(COL_4, Venue);
        cV.put(COL_5, Lat);
        cV.put(COL_6, Long);
        cV.put(COL_7, Addr);
        cV.put(COL_8, Date);
        cV.put(COL_9, Time);
        cV.put(COL_10, DayOfMonth);
        cV.put(COL_11, MonthName);
        long isInserted = myDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cV);
        if (isInserted == -1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }


    public Cursor getData() {

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        Log.e(Log_Tag, String.valueOf(date));
        Log.e(Log_Tag, String.valueOf(month+1));
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * From " + TABLE_NAME + " Where " + COL_10 + ">" + date + " AND " + COL_11 + ">=" + month, null);
        return res;
    }


    public Cursor getDataExpired() {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        Log.e(Log_Tag, String.valueOf(date));
        Log.e(Log_Tag, String.valueOf(month+1));
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * From " + TABLE_NAME + " Where " + COL_10 + "<" + date + " AND " + COL_11 + "<=" + month, null);
        return res;
    }


}
```

The values that I prints using Log.e are working fine.

Comment: You're storing dates as strings (e.g. `text` fields). That means **STRING** comparison rules apply. If you're not storing dates in most-significant-first ordering, e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`, then you're going to get wonky results. `9/1/2015` is going to come out GREATER than `10/1/2015`, because `9>1` is true...

Comment: forget about the comparison.. this is not using in this class.. Well if I select date of current month the comparison works in other activity because they are getting store in DB. but when I select date of further upcoming months the comparison does not works because nothing getting store in DB.

Comment: TL;DR, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its nothing to do with the comparison.. the comparison is working well. So there is no need to put that class code here.